# Laravel - insert query generated by create() method missing a column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to simply insert a row in `posts` table using a simple form, this is my `store()` method to insert a new row:

```
//FILE: PostsController.php

public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Using hard-coded values instead of actual form data, just to test
    Post::create([
        'title' => "test",
        'post' => "some text",
        'author' => "2",
        'slug' => "slug-value"
        ]);

    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

This is my model class for Posts:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'post', 'author', 'slug'
    ];

}
```

And following is my migration class (just showing `public function up()`, rest is same as any normal migration class) :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->longtext('post');
        $table->integer('author');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('tags')->nullable();
        $table->string('pics')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**PROBLEM:**  On submitting the form (i.e. on calling `store()` method in controller), it gives following error:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'slug' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `post`, `author`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, some text, 2, 2018-12-05 15:00:33, 2018-12-05 15:00:33)) ◀"

I don't understand why there is no `slug` column in the insert query generated by laravel. I've spent hours searching about this but not even SO has any answers related to it, most of them show adding into `$fillable` as a solution, but I already have that.

On my database, the table `posts` DOES contains the `slug` column. It shows it on tinker as well when I run `\Schema::getColumnListing('posts');`.

**PERHAPS HELPFUL:** I added the `slug` column later to the migration class, before that everything was working perfectly. I did run the `migrate:fresh` command after adding the column to migration class; and ofcourse until now I've tried all of `migrate:rollback` and then `migrate`, `migrate:refresh` etc... but nothing works.

Any idea why is it not including the `slug` column in insert query?

Comment: Mayby clearing the cache first?

Comment: I did clean the cache, no luck :(

Comment: Hi Echoes, your error SQL statement does not match the hard-coded values in the controller. Is that because you copy-pasted an old example? Or is there something stuck in a queue somewhere?

I sometimes inject this in my AppServiceProvider when debugging to see all the queries in detail:
`DB::listen(function ($query) {
            Log::debug("[sql] [query] " . $query->sql);
            Log::debug("[sql] [bindings] " . print_r($query->bindings, true));
        });
`

Comment: Ah yes I copy-pasted old example, my bad, I'll edit that.

Comment: Have you tried using another creation method to see if that works and if mass-assignment is the problem or the SQL is in the way somewhere?? 
E.g. `$post = new Post; $post->title = "title"; $post->slug = "test-slug"; $post->save();`

Comment: @T.Altena yes, I just tried, it is working this way. So I guess there is some problem in mass-assignment method. Anyway, it resolves my problem for now, I'll rather use this basic method instead of mass-assignment. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Rollback your migration, migrate again.

Then change this into your model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'post', 'author', 'slug', 'tags', 'pics'
];
```

Comment: As I wrote in my post, I already tried `migrate:rollback` and then migrate again, it doesn't works :( I think there some issue with mass-assignment method, because its working fine if I insert row using normal `$post->save()` method.

Comment: Did you change the model as i wrote?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added the 'slug' in the fillable attribute of your model then the data from the form doesn't contain the attribute 'slug'. You can dump the request in the controller using :

```
public function smtg(Request $request){
 dd($request);
}
```

Comment: Yes the form data does not contain attribute 'slug', I'm creating slug in the controller. But that doesn't matter because as shown in my post, I'm using simply the hardcoded values, so it does not matter whether slug is in my request or not, I reckon.

Comment: Try using forceCreate instead of create. If still the problem exist there might be problem with the database.

Answer (score 0):

The question is some months old now, but I just faced the same problem and found the solution (in my case) in a very different spot:
One trap is, if you set a

```
public function setSlugAttribute($value) {}
```

in your Post model. (Please note that the function is written in CamelCase even though the property is written snake_case.)
If you did not set anything in this function to the

```
$this->attributes['slug'] = ***;
```

There is actually nothing set to your instance and this field is not added to your query automatically created by the `Post::create()` function.

Maybe this helps somebody in the future!